# Minimum one field required in a list of multiple fields in magento admin form

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

How to validate minimum one field required in a list of multiple fields in magento admin form.

Form Field includes text box,select fields in admin form.

```
if(Validation) {
    Validation.addAllThese([ ['validation-myown','Please insert proper word',function(v,r){ var a = Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v);
   if(a == false){
       return true;
   }else{
       return false;
   }
} ], [ ] ]) }
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and provide more details. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Here is my code

Comment: if(Validation) {       
     Validation.addAllThese([     
        ['validation-myown','Please insert proper word',function(v,r){ 
                
                var a = Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v);
                
                
                if(a == false){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            } 
        ],
        [ ]   
        ])
    }

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using jquery:

```
$("#FORMID").submit(function(){

    var elemcount=0;
    $(this).find('input[type=text], select').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() != "") elemcount+=1;
    });

    // If the value of elemcount variable is 0, all elements are empty. 
    // Your select should have a default value as blank. 
    // If it is not so you have to add separate code for select and input.

 });
```